# Obvious deadlock situation is not occurred

Tags: mpi, deadlock

I'm completely stuck. This code

```
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
if(myrank==0) i=1;
if(myrank==1) i=0;
MPI_Send(sendbuf, 1, MPI_INT, i, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Recv(recvbuf, 1, MPI_INT, i, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
```

does work running on two processes. Why is there no deadlock?
Same thing with non-blocking version

```
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
if(myrank==0) i=1;
if(myrank==1) i=0;
MPI_Isend(sendbuf, 1, MPI_INT, i, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req);
MPI_Wait(&req, &status);
MPI_Irecv(recvbuf, 1, MPI_INT, i, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req);
MPI_Wait(&req, &status);
```

Logically there should be a blocking, but it is not. Why?
How do I force the MPI to block?

Comment: "stuck on an absence of deadlock" is very much intriguing. `MPI_Send()` returns when the send buffer can be reused, and that can happen before the message is sent, and even before a receive is posted. In this case, there is only one very small message, so it is likely sent in eager mode and `MPI_Send()` returns immediately. Do not assume that is always the case though. If you want to force a deadlock, you can use `MPI_Ssend()` or tweak your MPI config to disable eager mode send.

Comment: Exactly, I want to force a deadlock with the standard send mode.  Could you advise how to tweak MPI config to disable eager mode send?

Comment: It depends on your MPI library (vendor and version). Take the easy road and simply recompile with `-DMPI_Send=MPI_Ssend`.

Answer (score 0):

MPI has two kinds of point-to-point operations - blocking and non-blocking. This might be a bit confusing initially, especially when it comes to sending messages, but the blocking behaviour does not relate to the physical data transfer operation. It rather relates to the time period, in which MPI might still access the buffer (either send or receive) and therefore the application is not supposed to modify its content (with send operations) or may still read old garbage (with read operations).

When you make a blocking call to MPI, it only returns once it has finished using the send or the receive buffer. With receive operations this means that the message has been received and stored in the buffer, but with send operations things are more complex. There are several modes for the send operation:

- buffered -- data isn't sent immediately, but rather copied to a local user-supplied buffer and the call returns right after. The actual message transfer happens at some point in the future when MPI decides to do so. There is a special MPI call, `MPI_Bsend`, which always behaves this way. There are also calls for attaching and detaching the user-supplied buffer.
- synchronous -- MPI waits until a matching receive operation is posted and the data transfer is in progress. It returns once the entire message is in transit and the send buffer is free to be reused. There is a special MPI call, `MPI_Ssend`, which always behaves this way.
- ready -- MPI tries to send the message and it only succeeds if the receive operation has already been posted. The idea here is to skip the handshake between the ranks, which may reduce the latency, but it is unspecified what exactly happens if the receiver is not ready. There is a special call for that, `MPI_Rsend`, but it is advised to not use it unless you really know what you are doing.

`MPI_Send` invokes what is known as the standard send mode, which could be any combination of the synchronous and the buffered mode, with the latter using a buffer supplied by the MPI system and not the user-supplied one. The actual details are left to the MPI implementation and hence differ wildly.

It is most often the case that small messages are buffered while larger messages are sent synchronously, which is what you observe in your case, but one should never ever rely on this behaviour and the definition of "small" varies with the implementation and the network kind. A correct MPI program will not deadlock if all `MPI_Send` calls are replaced with `MPI_Ssend`, which means you must never assume that small messages are buffered. But a correct program will also not expect `MPI_Send` to be synchronous for larger messages and rely on this behaviour for synchronisation between the ranks, i.e., replacing `MPI_Send` with `MPI_Bsend` and providing a large enough buffer should not alter the program behaviour.

There is a very simple solution that always works and it frees you from having to remember to not rely on any assumptions -- simply use `MPI_Sendrecv`. It is a combined send and receive operation that never deadlocks, except when the send or the receive operation (or both) is unmatched. With send-receive, your code will look like this:

```c
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
if (myrank==0) i=1;
if (myrank==1) i=0;
MPI_Sendrecv(sendbuf, 1, MPI_INT, i, 99,
             recvbuf, 1, MPI_INT, i, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

Comment: This means that my program may or may not be blocked depending on some settings and buffer size. This does not suit me at all. Is there some reliable way to objectively determine whether deaclocks arise with MPI_Send use?

Comment: The only reliable way to cause a deadlock with `MPI_Send` is to alias it to `MPI_Ssend`, either using linker magic or by shadowing the library symbol with your own function that calls `MPI_Ssend`. Anything else requires tweaks to the MPI runtime and with some implementations it may not be possible at all. There is no universal switch. Add details about your particular MPI implementation to your question and someone may be able to tell you how to configure it.

Comment: Ok. What is about non-blocking function? I've add above example which againg don't want to be blocked.

Comment: `MPI_Isend` followed immediately by `MPI_Wait` is redundant as it is equivalent to `MPI_Send`. If `MPI_Send` is buffered, same applies to the combination of `MPI_Isend` and `MPI_Wait`. If you want the combo to block, use `MPI_Issend` followed by `MPI_Wait`.